# JavaScript reduce instance thoughts and ideas

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic, instance, reduce

after using a reduce to find the instance of the amount of times a year appears. how would I return that object so that on the year with the most occurrences return. Also any recommendation as to where I can see more logic and read different types of code ideas and functionality. This can be a book or website.

Comment: Some code might make you question more clear.